# How to define Affinity Groups for azure Web sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to the azure cloud, and i am trying to pick an Affinity Group for a web-site in the azure cloud,

Somehow it doesn't give me the option to do so in the region selection as like as it gives in the creation of instances and web-services process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't chose affinity group for a `Web Site`. This most probably will change once Web Sites become GA (Generally Available) (now they are in `preview`). So just select the region where you want your web site to be deployed.

**UPDATE**

> What does preview mean?

From [documentation (Support & SLA part)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/):

> Technical support for Web Sites, as a preview product, is currently
>   available only through community forums. Upon general availability, we
>   will provide technical support through Windows Azure Support.
>
> During preview, we do not provide any SLA to Web Sites. To learn more
>   about our SLA, please visit the SLA page.

Comment: thank you, can you explain to me what does it means that they are in preview ?

Comment: Websites are no longer in preview, but Affinity groups are still not available for websites

Comment: @RasmusChristensen - FYI - at this time, Affinity Groups are not supported by many Azure services (SQL Database as just one other example).